# How to add record to jTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

May I know how to add a record to jtable from json or array?

I can find only two methods from API Reference

I tried both, but not work, it always shows "No data available!"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.jtable.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/basic/jtable_basic.css" />
<script>
jQuery(document).ready
(
    function()
    {
        var jt=$('#jt').jtable
        (
            {
                title: 'this is title',
                fields: {
                    a: {
                        title: 'a'
                    },
                    b: {
                        title: 'b'
                    }
                }
            }
        );
        jt.jtable('load',{a:'aaa',b:'bbb'});

        jt.jtable('addRecord', {
            record: {
                a:'aaa',b:'bbb'
            }
        });
    }
);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="jt">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`load` method is used when you want to retrieve data to your table from server. If you want to add data by hand then `addRecord` is the right method to use. However: by default, jtable tries to add data also to server. If you don't have your server configured properly, then addRecord may fail too.

In this, if you just want to add data manually to the client side, provide `addRecord` with `clientOnly` parameter:

```
$('#jt').jtable('addRecord', {
   record: {
      a:'aaa',b:'bbb'
   },
   clientOnly: true
});
```

Full working demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FwQLM/2/)

Comment: If I set the paging:true, this is not work, it still send something to server. Can I use jtable with paging at client only?

Comment: The key selling point in jTable is Ajax support. Why do you use jTable if you don't need server-side communication? Why not use, say, DataTables? https://datatables.net/

Comment: If paging enabled you can't prevent it from reloading from server
https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/pull/666

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to add the data locally? According to the [documentation for `addRecord`](http://jtable.org/ApiReference#met-addRecord), you would need to specify the `clientOnly` option:

> **clientOnly** (boolean, default: false): If this is true, jTable does not add record to the server, only adds to the table.