# Adding search field to gson jtable

Tags: java, json, gson, jquery-jtable

I am attempting to add a search field on a specific column in a jtable that I have.  I'm currently using gson in order to pass json data.  Here is my controller:

```
public class gsonTestController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   String action = request.getParameter("action");
   if ( action != null) 
   {
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        response.setContentType("application/json");

        if (action.equals("list")) 
        {
                try
                {                                                                       
                // Add data to Student list
                studentList.add(new Student(1, "Grover", "IT", "xyz@xyz.com"));
                studentList.add(new Student(2, "Bugs Bunny", "ECE", "xyz@gmail.com"));
                studentList.add(new Student(3, "Taz", "MECH", "abc@gmail.com"));
                studentList.add(new Student(4, "Cookie Monster", "ECE", "efg@gmail.com"));
                studentList.add(new Student(5, "Billy the Kid", "CSC", "xyz@gmail.com"));
                studentList.add(new Student(6, "Dustin Hoffman", "CSC", "123@gmail.com"));
                studentList.add(new Student(7, "Obama", "ECE", "789@gmail.com"));
                studentList.add(new Student(8, "Adam Sandler", "ECE", "123@gmail.com"));
                studentList.add(new Student(9, "Pikachu", "IT", "xyz@gmail.com"));

                // Convert Java Object to Json
                String jsonArray = gson.toJson(studentList);

                //Return Json in the format required by jTable plugin
                jsonArray="{\"Result\":\"OK\",\"Records\":"+jsonArray+"}";
                System.out.println(jsonArray);
                response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                        String error="{\"Result\":\"ERROR\",\"Message\":"+ex.getMessage()+"}";
                        response.getWriter().print(error);
                }                               
                }
            }
         }
}
```

This accesses Student.java (basic getter/setter methods) and at the end, passes the json-ified data to the following script on the jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
                        title : 'Students List',
                        sorting: true,
                        defaultSorting: 'Name',
                        actions : {
                                listAction: 'gsonTestController?action=list',
                                createAction:'gsonTestController?action=create',
                                updateAction: 'gsonTestController?action=update',
                                deleteAction: 'gsonTestController?action=delete'
                        },
                        fields : {
                                studentId : {
                                        title : 'Student Id',
                                        width : '30%',
                                        key : true,
                                        list : true,
                                        create : true
                                },
                                name : {
                                        title : 'Name',
                                        width : '30%',
                                        edit : false
                                },
                                department : {
                                        title : 'Department',
                                        width : '30%',
                                        edit : true
                                },
                                emailId : {
                                        title : 'Email',
                                        width : '20%',
                                        edit : true
                                }
                        }
                });
                $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');
        });
</script>
```

The html is simply:

```
<div id="StudentTableContainer"></div>
```

When reading through the jtable documentation for filters, I was unable to find any sample code for implementing a filter using gson (as opposed to a dedicated server-side technology like php or ASP.NET).  Their filter demo page is located here:  http://www.jtable.org/Demo/Filtering

Now granted, my controller is just using hard-coded data for the time being since I don't have a datasource set up yet.  Eventually all of the data will be accessed via a DAO (in Spring MVC).  I am unfamiliar with ASP.NET, but I gather from the demos on the page that the basic idea is to set variables and filter the data based on the user-inputted values.  I'm just unsure as to how I would go about setting that up in my current structure.  I read through the gson user guide but I'm not really sure what I need to look for.  Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're using spring mvc, then I would suggest that you use spring-webmvc to implement your controller. That way, you don't have to use gson and don't have to worry about reading and writing json, as the framework does it for you -- you only have to accept and return pojos.

Comment: @EngineerDollery - really?  Can you provide a link that explains this functionality?  Everything I have read tells me I need to either use Jackson or GSON (or similar) in order to handle JSON data if I don't have a server-side technology in place that can handle the data.

Comment: Although this is an outdated approach (we don't realy use xml configuration an more)... http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program

Comment: A more up to date example: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: With spring-webmvc, most of the time you can get away with simply having jackson on the classpath, and whenever you have a method that produces or consumes json spring will do the translation for you.

Comment: Also, I'd be looking at jquery datatable, rather than jtable.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the links, I'll go through them now.  As for datatables, I've used it in the past but found it really buggy and inconsistent between browser types.  I also like the server-side processing of data when I have multiple tables on a page (as is the case with the current app).

Comment: Datatables supports server side processing, as you need it I think, and it should be a lot more compatible cross-browser than jtable as that's one of the key reasons it exists and is maintained by the jquery team.

Comment: I'll have to look into that, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

So, in their filter example

```
//Re-load records when user click 'load records' button.
$('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load', {
      name: $('#name').val(),
      cityId: $('#cityId').val()
   });
});

//Load all records when page is first shown
$('#LoadRecordsButton').click();
```

You can see they simply re-execute the request to the URL with the arguments writted by the user so the first thing you could do is to edit your `doPost` with

```
String studentName = request.getParameter("studentName");
```

check if passed, and filter the collections `studentList` to include only searched students

```
if (studentName != null) {
    Iterator<Student> iterator = studentList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      if (student.getName().startsWith(studentName)) {
          iterator.remove();
       }
    }
}
```

(*this code should be before the json serialization*)
(*if you use Guava, you can use Iterables.filter etc.*)

(*it's just an example how to implement the filter, if you take the data from the database you can filter the data using the SQL query*)

now inside `studentList` you will have only the students with the name provided without more code change.

The jQuery code will look like

```
$('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load', {
      studentName: $('#name').val()
   });
});
```

(*where `LoadRecordsButton` is the button to click to start search, `StudentTableContainer` is the table and `name` is the input text where write the name*)

You *could* avoid this code block if you want to work manually with the Json data and then use `addRecord` of `jTable` but after a small search i noticed it had some problems, so i would avoid it ([How to add record to jTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081930/how-to-add-record-to-jtable))